# Flutter playing music stored in assets folder

Tags: flutter, avaudioplayer

I would like to play a song that is stored in my assets folder but as far as I've researched there is only one way and that is the temporary folder method. Are there any other ways?
Below are something i have tried using the audioplayer package although its using a URL, it still doesn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
class songPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _songPageState createState() => _songPageState();
}

AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

class _songPageState extends State<songPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
               child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

           children: <Widget>[
            Text(
               'Page 2',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontFamily: 'FlamanteRoma' ,
                 fontSize: 50,
                 color: Colors.white,

               ),
             ),
             RaisedButton(
               child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
               onPressed: (){
                  playLocal() async {
                      int result = await audioPlayer.play('assets\audio\lovesong.mp3', isLocal: true);
                    }
                  print('It runs');
               })


           ],
         ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
I/flutter (30875): It runs
```

But it does not play,maybe the in-app volume?(my device volume is set to max)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer):

> If you get a MissingPluginException, try to `flutter build apk` on Android, or `flutter build ios`

Comment: tried and did not work, used a new package but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

did you include your assets in your pubspec.yaml?

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: Yes and still nothing

Comment: which plugin did u use?

Comment: Audioplayer and audioplayers

Answer (score 0):

To only play one song i managed to get a way using audio cache, simply declare the audio cache after implementing it then the path and finally in a onpressee button say audiocache.play